# Delta of FX Options, Different Currency in Trading Book - Trading Interview Question

Tags: options, fx, trading, market-making, delta

Having done stochastic analysis in university, together with tons of other math courses, do never prepare you for an actual interview in trading. Stumbled on what I believe might be an easy question, but do not see it at the moment.

Imagine a $1$ year ATM $EUR$ call $USD$ put strike $K=0.9090$, $S = 0.9090$, volatility $\sigma = 12\% $, $r_{EUR} = 3.96 \%$ and $r_{USD} = 3.57 \%$. Depending on the perspective we have, the delta will be difference as follows:

[image]

However, say that we are using a different currency on the trading book as our accounting currency. Take $JPY$ as an example with the current rate at $USDJPY = 100$. How would the delta in $JPY$ be affected if spot $EURUSD$ starts moving, say $+1\%$ move.

First, I would convert the delta in $USD$ to $JPY$, does it make sense? Then, instinctively the correlation between the currencies will have an effect. Since a fair assumption, is that an appreciation is $USD$ versus $JPY$ would depreciate $EURUSD$, negatively correlated. Hence, an even higher delta in the end?!

Got lost pretty fast, so would be much appreciated if someone can clarify and what assumptions you would add (take a simple  $\Gamma$ if needed, but felt like there was something else to the question).

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you mean by "First, I would convert the delta in USD to JPY". Do you mean you would hedge in JPY? re: "a fair assumption, is that an appreciation is USD versus JPY would depreciate EURUSD", why is that a "fair assumption"? You are assuming - to put it colloquially - that the move is USD-driven rather than JPY-driven. Perhaps USDJPY higher would be associated with EURJPY higher, i.e. EURUSD might be little changed.